# Embedding a private dash app with an iframe in a private html static site

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash

Embedding a private dash app with an iframe in a private html static site.

So, in my static html site i have something like:

```
## https://myawesomesite.com/mymaskedawesomeapp/
Content
...
<iframe src="https://myawesomeapp.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>
...
More Content
```

When i access https://myawesomeapp.com that is dash based and has dash_auth for basic auth. I get asked to log in and everything happens normally.

However, when i access https://myawesomesite.com/mymaskedawesomeapp/ i only get 401 not authorized and a message that says Login Required.

When i try the same thing, but i have authorized on the same browser, then the cookies get saved and i don't get the error, and the app displays as expected.

I don't need a single sign-in experience, or complicated JWT or Flask login pass.

I only need that my dash app when inside the iframe, asks the user to log in.